# Window Screen Shot?

Tags: windows, mac, vmware-fusion

I am running VMware Fusion 3.0.1 in a MacBook Pro and I have a Windows 7 guest OS. In the "Virtual Machine" menu item, there is a "Send Key" option and there is an option for "Print Scrn", but that takes the entire desktop and not just the window that I want to capture. How do I go about sending "Alt + Print Scrn"? I've tried holding down the "Alt" (option) key while trying the Virtual Machine -> Send Key -> Print Scrn, but that doesn't work. Or is my only option to attach an external Windows keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7 comes with a nice little application called Snipping Tool.  If you open your start menu and type it in the search it should come up.

Comment: For what it's worth, I LOVE MWSnap by Mirek, even on Windows 7. You can customize the keyboard shortcuts pretty well. Admittedly, I've not run it directly within a VM on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `command+shift+4`, this would let you take a custom sized screenshot as the OS X level. When you type this it give you a crosshair cursor that allows you to drag the size screenshot you want.

Comment: Read the question again. They want to take a screenshot of a window *inside the Windows VM*.

Comment: yes, I know and the OS X screen shot will capture content inside the VM so it isn't any different. Also, if the captured image needs to be used/manipulated inside the vm you can easily drag the screenshot image from your Mac desktop to the VM. Doesn't seem like an unreasonable option to me.

Answer (score 1):

My Mac keyboard has an F13, which apparently maps to Print Screen. So Option-F13 works just fine.

To help figure this out, or create an alternative, open the Preferences dialog, and in the Keyboard & Mouse page, you can add a Key Mapping. You can choose any key combo that maps to Alt-PrintScrn.

Click the + in the bottom right: a sheet drops down. In the From section, put the cursor in the entryfield, and press keys to figure out if the key has any secondary meaning. On my keyboard, F14 is Scroll Lock and F15 is Pause.